# Why does my mesh give wierd results when I apply a subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I tried to create this musical note. I started with a plane, and dragged, subdivided and extruded things to get this shape. I wonder if something is wrong because of the gray interior of that shape - seems abnormal but I don't know what it is.

[image]

If I add a subdivision surface modifier, it looks like this:

[image]

I know normals can get screwed up, but I recalculated and they look okay:

[image]

What else should I check? I don't know why it draws that normal in the middle empty space with no face. I tried to select a vertex or something in there, and I can't select anything.

Comment: That's probably because your mesh is triangulated, which is bad topology that the Subdiv modifier does not like.

Comment: Okay. I'm a beginner. So try to change those to quads and see what happens?

Comment: @someonewithpc is right in saying tris are not good with subsurf, but the result is so bad that let me think there should be also something else. I see for example "floating normals" around the middle of the last pic. Where do they came from? Is subsurf your only modifier? Consider the option to upload your blendfile to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I'd like to know where those normals come from, but since I can't select anything in that area, how can I know? Are those the "disconnected faces" or is that something else?

Comment: @RobN I created a similiar shape all quad and triangulated the tries look not so nice, but don't show the effect you have. I guess that there are duplicated vertices or non-manifold stuff.

Comment: It's difficult to be sure without examining the file, but I could wild guess that you have two big N-gon faces which are underlayed, hidden by the visible triangular faces. They are showing the normals in the centroid which for convex shapes can be outside the figure like [this](http://imgur.com/uWMvgS7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments your biggest issue is the topology. Here are a couple of things you could try straight off the bat:

- Install the [Meshlint](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint) addon and make sure all of your faces are quads
- Remove doubles (<kbd>W</kbd> *> Remove Doubles*)
- Recalculate normals (*Tool shelf > Shading/UVs > Normals: Recalculate*)

---

Also mentioned in the comments was that you have some disconnected faces. You can see two of them here:

[image]

Because of their position, I think whats happened is that you have two large single faces (n-gons) that's filled in a large portion of the top and bottom of the mesh, as well as all the little ones, so what you can do is in wireframe mode just try selecting all around the top portion of the model, see if you can find those stray faces.

---

Once you have sorted those things out, you can try a couple of things to make the edges a little bit cleaner with the sub surf on. I would recommend two edge loops around the middle section of the mesh, drag each one close but on on the top and bottom sections (I know I haven't worded this very well, I hope you can understand it), this will make the edges nice and crisp. Alternatively you could use mean creases, just select the edge loop at the very top and bottom and use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and adjust the slider.

Hope you understand all this! You should also checkout some of Jonothan Williamson's tutorials, he is very big on keeping good topology, something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMxvuUgOOf0) should do a lot of good for you!